# Django channels crashes whenever made a database call

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have this code and I am making a database call in the `connect` method.
The code runs fine if I comment the database call

```
async def connect(self):
    try:
        pk: int = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['pk']
        params: str = self.scope['query_string'].decode("utf-8")
        email: str = params.split('=')[1]
        # self.project: Project = await self.get_project(pk)

        self.room_name = "Room name!"
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % pk

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
          self.room_group_name,
          self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@database_sync_to_async
def get_project(self, pk: int) -> Project:
  return Project.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```

Can someone help me with this ? Thanks in advance

Output:

```
Django version 3.2.5, using settings 'server.settings'       
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.3 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /chat/1 [127.0.0.1:60496]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/1 [127.0.0.1:60496]
1006
```

Comment: Please share the stack trace

Comment: It just disconnects and gives 1006

Comment: But which error is shown by channels?

Comment: I am trying to print exceptions but still I am getting nothing

Comment: try to move the ```await self.accept()``` call before the database call  ```await self.get_project(pk)```.

Comment: Thanks @Aprimus it works now! Just one question though... `self.accept()` should always be the first step ?